# Search for pattern and create file with the same name

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, json

Here's a simple line of my usage:

```
grep -i '"location_country":"country name"' file.txt >> sample.txt
```

I'm searching a large file with multiple countries and what I would like to do is create a text file with the country name dynamically and store all matches from the same country into that file, which means `country name.txt` for every occurrence.

something like this

```
grep -i '"location_country":"(.+)"' file.txt >> \1.txt
```

Example of data:

```
{"full_name":"name1","location_country":"united kingdom"}
{"full_name":"name2","location_country":"united states"}
{"full_name":"name3","location_country":"china"}
```

So I need to create 3 separate text files with country names e.g. `united kingdom.txt` contains:

```
{"full_name":"name1","location_country":"united kingdom"}
```

I'm already using bash scripting so I don't mind that, How could I achieve this? I am using a Linux machine.

Comment: If this is a JSON file, then using `grep` is not the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: @they what do suggest to use?

Comment: @Cyb3r no, we need an example of the input file. This isn't possible using just `grep`, it will take more tools and we need to understand what kind of data you will be handling. For example, can you have multiple words in a name? With spaces? Can you have `Canada` in one line and `canada` in another? If so, what name should the output file have? Please [edit] your question and add i) an example input file covering as many cases as possible, and ii) the output you want to see from that example. That way, we can test our answers and be sure we are giving you a solution that works for you.

Comment: @terdon apologies for any confusion I may have caused, I cannot to post an example of the data because it's a private data of my clients, but the only thing I need to do is capture the country name and use it as a file name would that be possible?

Comment: We really can't help without an example. If you can't share the actual data, then change the value around or create a similar file with dummy data and show us the dummy. But at the moment, you are asking us to help you parse data we don't have access to and that's just not possible. There are too many possible differences and variables involved.  Surely you can make a small example file with no names or no real names but which can accurately represent what you really have.

Comment: @terdon How about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file consists of a set of JSON objects.  Each object contains a `.location_country` key.  From each object we may create a shell command that writes a serialized copy of the object itself to a file named by the value of the `.location_country` key.  These shell commands could then be executed by the shell.

Using `jq`,

```bsh
jq -r '"printf \"%s\\n\" \(. | @json | @sh) >\(.location_country|@sh).txt"' file.txt
```

The serialized object may be created using the `@json` operator in `jq`, which will emit a JSON encoded string containing the input document, in this case the current object.  This is then fed to `@sh` to properly quote the string for the shell.  The `@sh` operator is also used for creating part of the output filename from the value of the `.location_country` key.

The command essentially creates shell code that would invoke `printf`, outputting the current object and redirecting the output to a specific file.

Given your example data in `file.txt`, this would emit the following:

```bsh
printf "%s\n" '{"full_name":"name1","location_country":"united kingdom"}' >'united kingdom'.txt
printf "%s\n" '{"full_name":"name2","location_country":"united states"}' >'united states'.txt
printf "%s\n" '{"full_name":"name3","location_country":"china"}' >'china'.txt
```

You would be able to redirect this to a separate file and run it with `sh` to execute the commands, or you could use `eval` in the shell directly:

```bsh
eval "$( jq ...as above... )"
```

Since we're using a proper JSON parser, `jq`, the above would work even if the input JSON document is not formatted with a single object per line.

```bsh
$ cat file.txt
{
  "full_name": "name1",
  "location_country": "united kingdom"
}
{
  "full_name": "name2",
  "location_country": "united states"
}
{
  "full_name": "name3",
  "location_country": "china"
}
```

```bsh
$ jq -r '"printf \"%s\\n\" \(. | @json | @sh) >\(.location_country|@sh).txt"' file.txt
printf "%s\n" '{"full_name":"name1","location_country":"united kingdom"}' >'united kingdom'.txt
printf "%s\n" '{"full_name":"name2","location_country":"united states"}' >'united states'.txt
printf "%s\n" '{"full_name":"name3","location_country":"china"}' >'china'.txt
```

```bsh
$ eval "$( jq -r '"printf \"%s\\n\" \(. | @json | @sh) >\(.location_country|@sh).txt"' file.txt )"
$ ls
china.txt           file.txt            united kingdom.txt  united states.txt
$ cat 'united kingdom.txt'
{"full_name":"name1","location_country":"united kingdom"}
```

Comment: It worked good but if there's multiple occurrences of the same country it'll just overwrite the file instead of appending to it. Anyway to solve this? Also how would I use it with something like zcat to read the buffer from a compressed file instead of static file?

Comment: Never mind got working properly now thank you for you effort!

Comment: After more testing this crashes my terminal and exits, I think it uses memory to store the whole text which causes the crash, I have already stated it's a large file. Any solution? I'm using wsl in windows 10.

Comment: @Cyb3r If you have many instances of the same country, use `>>` rather than `>` in the code.  If the data is huge, use `jq ... | sh -s` to run the code instead of using `eval`.  If you read from a compressed file, then pipe from `zcat` into `jq`.  One person's "huge file" is another person's "tiny bit of data", so I wasn't sure exactly what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments below, this should do what you want using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and handling of many concurrently open files:

```
awk 'match($0,/"location_country":"([^"]+)"/,a) { print > (a[1] ".txt") }' file
```

For execution speed a decorate/sort/use/undecorate approach would probably be best though, e.g.:

```
awk -v OFS='"' 'match($0,/"location_country":"[^"]+"/) { print substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-21), $0 }' file |
sort -t'"' -k1,1 |
awk -F'"' '$1!=prev { close(out); out=$1 ".txt"; prev=$1 } { print > out }' |
cut -d'"' -f2-
```

and that will work with any sort, awk, and cut.

---

Original answer:

If your data is always that simple/regular then all you need is this with GNU awk (to handle many concurrently open output files):

```
awk -F'"' '{ print > ($5 ".txt") }' file
```

or this with any awk:

```
awk -F'"' '{
    out = $5 ".txt"
    if ( !seen[out]++ ) {
        printf "" > out
    }
    print >> out
    close(out)
}' file
```

The above will work no matter how large your input file is as long as you have disk space available to create the output files in.

You can do it more efficiently by sorting on the country name first if you care to do that:

```
sort -t'"' -k5,5 file |
awk -F'"' '$5 != prev{ close(out); out=$5 ".txt"; prev=$5 } { print > out }'
```

That last script will work with any sort and any awk but it could rearrange the order of the input lines for each country. If you care about that and have GNU sort then add the `-s` argument. If you care and don't have  GNU sort let me know as there's a pretty simple workaround.

Comment: For the propose of explaining my point I wrote a dummy data but it's actually more than that, the file is very large with many fields having multiple occurrences of the same country, and I don't care about sorting them out.

Comment: OK, so - does the answer I posted work for you or not? You may have to change `5`s to whatever other number the is the real `"`-separated field that contains the country of course.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because you're searching for the fifth quote which is not always true. The only static text you should look for is the field name `location_country`. Although the answer using `jq` is working I was wondering which is faster `awk` or `jq`?

Comment: Please edit the example in your question to show that the target field isn't always in the same location. [You said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674732/search-for-pattern-and-create-file-with-the-same-name/674795?noredirect=1#comment1273635_674746) the jq answer wasn't working for you - if it is working for you now then you don't need any alternative solution and it'll be the most robust whether an awk one would be faster or not (I've no idea which would be faster).

Comment: Yeah it was causing a crash when using `eval` but after using `sh -s` it works fine. I will mark it as solved and accept the answer. Thank you for you effort!

Comment: You're welcome.  I updated my answer to show how to do what you want with awk anyway.  I'd be interested in learning if there is any time difference between the awk vs jq+sh approaches if you feel like testing both and posting that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

**Input**

```
$ cat input_file
{"full_name":"name1","location_country":"united kingdom"}
{"full_name":"name2","location_country":"united states"}
{"full_name":"name3","location_country":"china"}
{"full name":"name12","location":"china"}
{"full name":"name11","location":"china"}
```

```
awk -F"[\"|:]" '$10~/[A-Za-z]/ {print > $10".txt"}' input_file
```

**Output**

```
$ cat china.txt
{"full_name":"name3","location_country":"china"}
{"full name":"name12","location":"china"}
{"full name":"name11","location":"china"}

$ cat united\ kingdom.txt
{"full_name":"name1","location_country":"united kingdom"}

$ cat united\ states.txt
{"full_name":"name2","location_country":"united states"}
```